# Property 'theme' does not exist when using typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, themes, material-ui

I am creating a ReactJS starter project using typescript with material-ui v1.x beta.

The themes as explained at: https://material-ui-1dab0.firebaseapp.com/customization/themes/
do not work. Typescript complains about the property 'theme' not existing. I have been fiddling with the index.d.ts in @types/material-ui replacing the interface 'muiTheme' to 'theme' which results in a whole lot of other errors.

When using 'muiTheme' property instead the errors are gone, however only the default colours are used indicating my custom theme is not used at all.

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider } from 'material-ui/styles';
import createMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/theme';
import createPalette from 'material-ui/styles/palette';
import { teal, bluegrey, red } from 'material-ui/colors';
import Button from 'material-ui/Button';

const theme: any = createMuiTheme({
  palette: createPalette({
    primary: teal, // Purple and green play nicely together.
    accent: {
      ...bluegrey,
      A400: '#00e677',
    },
    error: red,
  }),
});

function Palette() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <div>
        <Button color="primary">
          {'Primary'}
        </Button>
        <Button color="accent">
          {'Accent'}
        </Button>
      </div>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Typescript:

```
(21,23): error TS2339: Property 'theme' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<MuiThemeProvider> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNod...'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using material-ui V1 then you do not use the @types anymore the types are shipped with the package. Simply point your tsconfig file to it in the `"types": "material-ui"` and have `node_modules` in the `"typeRoots"` section.

Example

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": [
       "node_modules/@types",
        "node_modules"
    ],
    "types": [
        "node", "jest", "lodash", "react",
        "react-dom", "react-redux", "redux-logger", "material-ui",
        "react-router-dom", "react-router-redux",
        "redux", "binary-type-tree", "redux-form",
        "tedb", "react-tap-event-plugin",
        "react-hot-loader", "material-ui-icons"
    ],
    "outDir": "dist"
},
"include": [
    "src",
    "node_modules/**/*.d.ts",
    "node_modules/@types/**/*.d.ts"
],
```

This of course will change your project, the project had almost a complete rewrite and I had to rework my project to use V1.

Comment: Note sure where it went wrong, but I started from scratch following the examples of the Material-UI website and now everything works as designed. As mjwrazor mentioned, installing @types for material-ui is not needed anymore.

Comment: You are saving my life! I was struggling with duplicated types from the beginning of the project. Removing `@types` resolves compilation and editor problems. Cheers!

Answer (score 46):

For anyone running into a similar error message in 2020, my issue was that I was importing makeStyles from the @material-ui/styles package. Switching to the preferred @material-ui/core/styles package gives you the correct types.

eg. Change:

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';`

to

`import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';`

See [this github issue](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/17854) discussing the preferred import. I believe the former was introduced with MUI 3 as a temporary shim for some style conversions they were working on.

Comment: This solved a similar error I was receiving, `Property 'spacing' does not exist on type 'DefaultTheme'.`. Thanks mate!

Comment: I had a similar problem - had to replace `import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core'` with `import { createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles'`, and update the corresponding `declare module` .

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) => ({

}));
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer by @Blaine Garrett is very Good but I fixed the error by using

> import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

as using `import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';` was giving me another error.

Answer (score 1):

> `<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>`

The type definition for `mui` is out of date / incorrect. This wouldn't be a problem if mui was written in TypeScript.

## More

Be the change and provide a fix here : https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/material-ui/index.d.ts as a PR.

## Prefer TypeScript first packages

e.g. blueprintjs as they do not suffer from such problems. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/nodejs.html